# Issue with linking libraries built with gnat

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ada, gnat

When trying to build some test cases (just programs written in Ada), I get the following error:

```
gcc -c -shared decimaltests.adb
gnatbind -x decimaltests.ali
gnatlink decimaltests.ali -lGenerics -lNumerics -lTesting
/usr/bin/ld: decimaltests: hidden symbol `_Unwind_Resume' in 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.1/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gnatlink: error when calling /usr/bin/gcc
gnatmake: *** link failed.
```

I'm building them with `gnatmake -shared *.ad{b,s} -largs -lGenerics -lNumerics -lTesting` Clearly this isn't a problem with building the sources, but just to further confirm that, I copied the sources into this directory and built using `gnatmake -shared *.ad{b,s}` which built the tests just fine.

The dependent libraries are built and installed into a path gnat searches through. It doesn't seem to be an issue of not finding those. Not sure what's going on here.

All the libraries are built with `gnatmake -O2 -fPIC -shared *.ad{b,s}` as well as any relevant library dependencies. All libraries that depend on these can still be built. It's only even programs that depend on the libraries that throw this error, and always the same error.

*Update:* Building the libraries using gprbuild and then installing them with gprinstall seems to work similarly, except now the error is as follows:

```
decimaltests.o: In function `_ada_decimaltests':
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `testing__start'
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance'
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance'
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance'
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance'
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance'
decimaltests.o:decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x23f): more undefined references to 
`generics__testing__default_tolerance' follow
decimaltests.o: In function `_ada_decimaltests':
decimaltests.adb:(.text+0x14f5): undefined reference to `testing__stop'
/usr/lib/numerics//libNumerics.so: undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__not_started@SYMS'
/usr/lib/numerics//libNumerics.so: undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__pass@SYMS'
/usr/lib/numerics//libNumerics.so: undefined reference to 
`generics__testing__fail@SYMS'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gprbuild: link of decimaltests.adb failed
```

So I looked through the symbols table for both build methods and noticed, in both cases, the symbol most definitely exists, but the reference to it seems to be the wrong location. I'll try building on different platforms/compilers and update again if anything relevant comes up.

Comment: Have you considered using project files and `gprbuild` to control the building and use of the shared libraries?  `gnatmake` is the low-level interface to GNAT.  Ordinary, lazy developers like you and me are supposed to use project files.

Comment: Yes. This has been something I've looked into before, and found that for my specific needs, gprbuilds failed me terribly.

That being said however, building a package under them and looking at the build flags has been useful in the past for solving other related issues, so that's probably what I'll need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both processes correctly build the libraries and test programs, and the test programs run properly, on different platforms. To further confirm that this is a bug, I've installed a different GCC toolchain and repeated the builds under the original platform, and this problem did not arise. I'll be filing a bug report.

Comment: I'd be cautious about assuming it's an actual bug. It looks like the sort of thing that happens when one compiler version finds (thanks to path or environment quirks like LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ) libraries left over from  another compiler. Therefore it's possible that the simple act of a clean compiler install removed the quirk.

Comment: I'll do a fresh install of that same version on a fresh install of that same platform and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Do you mind specifying the version9s) that work and don't work please.  I'm wondering if I have the same problem or if its just a path issue as Brian commented.

Comment: This was 9 months ago. How am I supposed to remember what versions were installed then? I don't even remember what machine I was doing this on.